# How do I Add Component to View Items in this Shopping Cart App Frontend?

Tags: reactjs

frontend/App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


import cusProfile from './Customer-components/cusProfile';
import cartlist from './Customer-components/cartlist';
import purchase from './Customer-components/purchase';
import viewItems from './Customer-components/viewItems';

import addItem from './Trader_components/addItem';
import addPromotions from './Trader_components/addPromotions';
import editItem from './Trader_components/editItem';
import traderProfile from './Trader_components/traderProfile';
import viewCustomer from './Trader_components/viewCustomer';
import viewInventry from './Trader_components/viewInventry';
import viewPromotions from './Trader_components/viewPromotions';




function App() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<cartlist/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/cusProfile" element={<cusProfile/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/viewCustomer" element={<viewCustomer/>} exact/>
            
            <Route path="/purchase" element={<purchase/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/viewItems" element={<viewItems/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/addItem" element={<addItem/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/addPromotions" element={<addPromotions/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/editItem" element={<editItem/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/traderProfile" element={<traderProfile/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/viewCustomer" element={<viewCustomer/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/viewInventry" element={<viewInventry/>} exact/>
            <Route path="/viewPromotions" element={<viewPromotions/>} exact/>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
       
        <div>
        
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

frontend/index/jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './app.jsx';

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>)
```

frontend/index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root">
            </div>
            <script type="module" src="index.jsx"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

frontend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
  "author": "kanishka",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

frontend/Customer-components/cartlist.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function cartlist({addItem}) {

    return (
        <div className="cart">
            <h4>Cart Items</h4>
            {addItem.length === 0 && (<div>No items Added Yet.</div>)}

            <div>
                {addItem.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        {item.itemname}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

frontend/Customer-components/cusProfile.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  cusProfile = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();
   
    const [username, setusername] = useState('');
    const [fullname, setfullname] = useState('');
    const [email, setemail] = useState('');
    const [mobilenumber, setmobilenumber] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');

    // const handleInputs = (e)=>{
    //     setInput((statebefore)=>({
    //         ...statebefore,
    //         [e.target.name] : e.target.value,       
    //  }))
    // }

    // const sendData = async()=>{
    //     await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/customer/profile",{
    //         username : (input.username),
    //         fullname : (input.fullname),
    //         password : (input.password),
    //         mobilenumber : (input.mobilenumber)
    //     }).then((res)=>{
    //         res.data
    //     })
        
    // }

    


    const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/customer/profile`, {
        username,
        fullname,
        email,
        password,
        mobilenumber
    }
    //{setusername='',setfullname='',setpassword='',setmobilenumber=''}
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/customer"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> create new customer </h1>
        <form>
        <label for="fname">User Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="User ID" placeholder = "Enter User Name" onChange={(e)=>setusername(e.target.value)} /><br/>
         <label for="lname">Full Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Full Name" placeholder = "Enter Full Name" onChange={(e)=>setfullname(e.target.value)} /><br/>
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br/>
        <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder = "Enter Email" onChange={(e)=>setemail(e.target.value)} /><br/>
        <label for="lname">Password:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder = "Enter Password" onChange={(e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)} /><br/><br/>
        <label for="lname">Mobile No:</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="Email" placeholder = "Enter Mobile No" onChange={(e)=>setmobilenumber(e.target.value)} /><br/><br/>
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default cusProfile
```

frontend/Customer-components/purchase.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  purchase = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [itemname, setitemname] = useState('');
    const [cardNo, setcardNo] = useState('');
    const [cvvnum, setcvvnum] = useState('');
    const [expdate, setexpdate] = useState('');
    
  
   

        const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/payment/save`, {
        itemname,
        cardNo,
        cvvnum,
       expdate
       
       
    }
    
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/payment"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> Add payment</h1>
        <form>
       
         <label for="iname">Item Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Name" placeholder = "Enter Item Name" onChange={(e)=>setitemname(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="card">Card No:</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="Card No:" placeholder = "Enter Card No" onChange={(e)=>setcardNo(e.target.value)} /><br/>


        <label for="cvv">CVV No:</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="Cvv No" placeholder = "Enter CVV Number" onChange={(e)=>setcvvnum(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="expdate">Expire Date:</label><br/>
        <input type="date" id="Expire Date" placeholder = "Enter Expire Date" onChange={(e)=>setexpdate(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default purchase
```

frontend/Customer-components/viewItems.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  purchase = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [itemname, setitemname] = useState('');
    const [cardNo, setcardNo] = useState('');
    const [cvvnum, setcvvnum] = useState('');
    const [expdate, setexpdate] = useState('');
    
  
   

        const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/payment/save`, {
        itemname,
        cardNo,
        cvvnum,
       expdate
       
       
    }
    
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/payment"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> Add payment</h1>
        <form>
       
         <label for="iname">Item Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Name" placeholder = "Enter Item Name" onChange={(e)=>setitemname(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="card">Card No:</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="Card No:" placeholder = "Enter Card No" onChange={(e)=>setcardNo(e.target.value)} /><br/>


        <label for="cvv">CVV No:</label><br/>
        <input type="number" id="Cvv No" placeholder = "Enter CVV Number" onChange={(e)=>setcvvnum(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="expdate">Expire Date:</label><br/>
        <input type="date" id="Expire Date" placeholder = "Enter Expire Date" onChange={(e)=>setexpdate(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default purchase
```

frontend/Trader_components/addItem.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  addItem = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [itemId, setitemId] = useState('');
    const [itemname, setitemname] = useState('');
    const [price, setprice] = useState('');
    
  
   

        const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/inventry/additems`, {
        itemId,
        itemname,
        price
       
       
    }
    
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/inventry"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> Add Item </h1>
        <form>
        <label for="itemid">Item ID:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item ID" placeholder = "Enter Item ID" onChange={(e)=>setitemId(e.target.value)} /><br/>

         <label for="iname">Item Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Name" placeholder = "Enter Item Name" onChange={(e)=>setitemname(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="price">Item Price:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Price" placeholder = "Enter Item Price" onChange={(e)=>setprice(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default addItem;
```

frontend/Trader_components/addPromotions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  addPromotions = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [itemname, setitemname] = useState('');
    const [type, settype] = useState('');
    const [discount, setdiscount] = useState('');
    
  
   

        const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/promotions/save`, {
        itemname,
        type,
        discount
       
       
    }
    
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/promotions"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> Add Promotions </h1>
        <form>
        <label for="itemname">Item Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Name" placeholder = "Enter Item Name" onChange={(e)=>setitemname(e.target.value)} /><br/>

         <label for="itype">Item Type:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Type" placeholder = "Enter Item Type" onChange={(e)=>settype(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        <label for="discount">Item Discount:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Item Discount" placeholder = "Enter Item Discount" onChange={(e)=>setdiscount(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default addPromotions
```

frontend/Trader_components/traderProfile.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const  traderProfile = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [userId, setuserId] = useState('');
    const [name, setname] = useState('');
    const [password, setpassword] = useState('');
    const [email, setemail] = useState('');
  
   

        const postData = () => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/admin/profile`, {
        userId,
        name,
       
        password,
        email
       
    }
    //{setusername='',setfullname='',setpassword='',setmobilenumber=''}
    ).then((response)=>{console.log(response)}).catch((err)=>{
        alert(err)
    })
    }
  return (

    
    <div>

        <Link to={"/admin"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
        <center>
        <h1> Add New Trader </h1>
        <form>
        <label for="userid">User ID:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="User ID" placeholder = "Enter User ID" onChange={(e)=>setuserId(e.target.value)} /><br/>

         <label for="name"> Name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="Full Name" placeholder = "Enter Name" onChange={(e)=>setname(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        

        <label for="lname">Password:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder = "Enter Password" onChange={(e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)} /><br/><br/>

        <label for="email">Email:</label><br/>
        <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder = "Enter Email" onChange={(e)=>setemail(e.target.value)} /><br/>

        
        <button onClick={postData} type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </form>
        </center>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default traderProfile
```

frontend/Trader_components/viewCustomer.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'



const viewCustomer = () => {

  const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/customer/viewAll`).then((resposne)=>{
      setAPIData(resposne.data)
    })
},[])

  return (
    <div className="viewcustomer">
       <Link to={"/customer"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
      <center>
      <h2>View Customers</h2>
      <table >
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Fullname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Mobile number</th>
    <th>Password</th>
  </tr>
  {APIData.map((data)=>{return(<tr>
    <td>{data.username}</td>
    <td>{data.fullname}</td>
    <td>{data.email}</td>
    <td>{data.mobilenumber}</td>
    <td>{data.password}</td>
  </tr>)})}
  
  </tbody>
  
</table>
      </center>
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default viewCustomer
```

frontend/Trader_components/viewPromotions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'



const viewPromotions = () => {

  const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/promotions/get`).then((resposne)=>{
      setAPIData(resposne.data)
    })
},[])

  return (
    <div className="viewpromotions">
       <Link to={"/promotions"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link>  
      <center>
      <h2>View Promotions</h2>
      <table >
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Type</th>
    <th>Discount</th>
  </tr>
  {APIData.map((data)=>{return(<tr>
    <td>{data.itemname}</td>
    <td>{data.type}</td>
    <td>{data.discount}</td>
   
  </tr>)})}
  
  </tbody>
  
</table>
      </center>
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default viewPromotions
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So, Funnily enough, I've managed to crack the code right after I posted this here.

frontend/Trader_components/editItem.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const  Edititem = ()=> {

    const history = useNavigate();
   
    const [itemId, setitemId] = useState('');
    const [itemname, setitemname] = useState('');
    const [price, setprice] = useState('');
    const [id,setID] = useState(null);

    const item = {
        itemId,
        itemname,
        price
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      setID(localStorage.getItem('ID'))
      setitemId(localStorage.getItem('Item ID'))  
      setitemname(localStorage.getItem('Item Name'))
      setprice(localStorage.getItem('Price'))
      
    }, [])
    
    const updateApi = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault();
      axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/inventry/${id}`,{
           itemId,
           itemname,
           price 
      }).then((res)=>{
          console.log(res.data)
      })
    }

  return (
    <div>
       <Link to={"/viewitems"} >
            <button>Back</button>
        </Link> 
        <center>
        <h1>Update Items</h1>
        <form>
        <label for="Item Code">Item Id:</label><br/>
        <input type="text"  placeholder = "Enter Item Id" value={itemcode} onChange={(e)=>setitemcode(e.target.value)} /><br/>
         <label for="itemname">itemname:</label><br/>
        <input type="text"  placeholder = "Enter item Name" value={itemname} onChange={(e)=>setitemname(e.target.value)} /><br/>
        <label for="price">price:</label><br/>
        <input type="number"  placeholder = "Enter Item Price" value={price} onChange={(e)=>setprice(e.target.value)} /><br/><br/>
        
        <button onClick={updateApi} type="submit">Update</button>
        
        </form>
        </center>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Edititem
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is best to create the frontend using react using this format.
Create a React App from Scratch in 2021
Become a better coder by learning what create-react-app is doing under the hood.
You’ve worked on a few (or maybe a lot) of React projects but may have only started your own project by using create-react-app.

Create-react-app is great for beginners who just want to get their hands into some React code without going through the trouble of configuring the project with Webpack and Babel.

But you’re stronger now. You’re owning React….and now it’s time to soldier on by creating your project from the ground up. The “React” equivalent of building your car engine from scratch.

Fear not. You’ve got this.

Create project directory
First, create a new directory and cd into it.

```
mkdir my-app-from-scratch && cd my-app-from-scratch
```

Next, let’s initialize the app with npm to manage all our dependencies.

```
npm init -y
```

Great! Now you have your package.json file set up.

Install Dependencies
Next up, let’s install all the dependencies we’ll need for this application. Run this command and continue below for a breakdown of everything we just installed.

```
npm i webpack babel-loader @babel/preset-react @babel/core babel-preset-react html-webpack-plugin webpack-dev-server css-loader style-loader @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties webpack-cli -D && npm i react react-dom -S
```

What we just installed:

Webpack: bundles all our files into one file
babel-loader: works with Webpack to transpile ES6+ into ES5 which is supported by older browsers
@babel/preset-react: extends Babel support to JSX
html-webpack-plugin: “simplifies the creation of HTML files to serve your Webpack bundles” -https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/
webpack-dev-server: allows you to use Webpack with a development server that provides live reloading.
webpack-cli: “webpack CLI provides a flexible set of commands for developers to increase speed when setting up a custom Webpack project.” -https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cli
css-loader: allows Webpack to convert the CSS file into a JavaScript string.
style-loader: inserts the JavaScript string into HTML dom.
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties: “This plugin transforms static class properties as well as properties declared with the property initializer syntax” -https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
react: JavaScript library
react-dom: “Serves as the entry point to the DOM and server renderers for React” -https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom
Add src directory and index.js file

```
mkdir src && cd src && touch index.js
```

Add file src/index.html
While still inside the src directory, type this command into the terminal:

```
touch index.html
```

Your file tree should currently look like this:

```
my-app-from-scratch/
┣ node_modules/
┣ src/
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ index.js
┣ package-lock.json
┗ package.json
```

Great!

Now let’s add some starter code
Inside of src/index.html add this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=”en”>
<head>
 <meta charset=”utf-8">
 <title>My React App from Scratch</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id=”app”></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside of src/index.js add this code:

```
import ReactDOM from ‘react-dom’;
import React from ‘react’;
const App = () => {
 return <h1>This is my React app!</h1>;
 }
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById(‘app’));
```

Configure Webpack & Babel
Awesome. Now it’s time to rig up our Webpack and Babel configuration files. These files allow us to customize Webpack & Babel to handle things like JSX and CSS inside of our project.

In the root directory, type this into your terminal:

```
touch .babelrc && touch webpack.config.js
```

Your file tree should look like this:

```
my-app-from-scratch/
┣ node_modules/
┣ src/
 ┣ index.html
 ┗ index.js
┣ .babelrc
┣ package-lock.json
┣ package.json
┗ webpack.config.js
```

Inside of webpack.config.js add this code:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require(“html-webpack-plugin”);
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
 template: “./src/index.html”,
 filename: “./index.html”
});
module.exports = {
mode: ‘development’,
  module: {
    rules: [{
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   use: {
     loader: “babel-loader”
   }
 },
  {
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [“style-loader”, “css-loader”]
  }
]},
 plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

Inside of .babelrc add this code:

```
{
 “presets”: [“@babel/preset-react”],
 “plugins”: [“@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties”]
}
```

Add ‘start’ script to package.json
Inside of package.json, add this code in scripts.

```
"start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js"
```

Your package.json file should look like this:

```
{
 “name”: “my-app-from-scratch “,
 “version”: “1.0.0”,
 “description”: “”,
 “main”: “webpack.config.js”,
 “scripts”: {
   “test”: “echo \”Error: no test specified\” && exit 1",
   "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js"
},
 “keywords”: [],
 “author”: “”,
 “license”: “ISC”,
 “devDependencies”: {
 “@babel/preset-react”: “⁷.12.13”,
 “babel-core”: “⁶.26.3”,
 “babel-loader”: “⁸.2.2”,
 “babel-preset-react”: “⁶.24.1”,
 “css-loader”: “⁵.0.2”,
 “html-webpack-plugin”: “⁵.1.0”,
 “style-loader”: “².0.0”,
 “webpack”: “⁵.22.0”,
 “webpack-cli”: “⁴.5.0”,
 “webpack-dev-server”: “³.11.2”
 },
 “dependencies”: {
 “react”: “¹⁷.0.1”,
 “react-dom”: “¹⁷.0.1”
 }
}
```

Test to see your app running in the browser
Now it’s time for our moment-of-truth to see all our hard work in action!

In the root directory terminal, run

```
npm run start
```

You should see your app running at http://localhost:8080/ in the browser.